# Animating image thumbnail to parent div and changing src to bigger image

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation

I want to be able to animate a div when the user clicks and for this div to expand to fit the parent div size. I also want the image src to change when it animates.

I've managed to animate it but I can't seem to get it to change the image src.

This is what I have so far:

```js
$('figure').click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  // Get square ID
  var currentId = $(this).attr('id'),
    extraimg = $('#' + currentId).clone(),
    currentOffset = $('#' + currentId).offset(),
    parent = $('.wrapper'),
    parentOffset = parent.offset(),
    bigImageSrc = $(this).children("a").attr("src");
  extraimg.find("img")
    .attr("src", bigImageSrc)
    .css({
      'position': 'absolute',
      'top': currentOffset.top,
      'left': currentOffset.left,
      'margin': 0
    })
    .appendTo(parent)
    //make bigger
    .animate({
      'height': parent.height(),
      'width': parent.width(),
      'top': parentOffset.top,
      'left': parentOffset.left
    }, 1500)
    .on('click', function() {
      $(this).stop(true).remove();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<figure id="photo-1" itemprop="associatedMedia" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject" class=" scene_element scene_element--fadein">
  <a href="http://localhost:8888/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/golden-horizon-sunset.jpg" itemprop="contentUrl" data-size="2304x1536'">

    <img width="576" height="384" src="http://localhost:8888/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/golden-horizon-sunset-576x384.jpg" class="attachment-image-md size-image-md wp-post-image" alt="" srcset="http://localhost:8888/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/golden-horizon-sunset-576x384.jpg 576w, http://localhost:8888/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/golden-horizon-sunset-300x200.jpg 300w, http://localhost:8888/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/golden-horizon-sunset-768x512.jpg 768w, http://localhost:8888/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/golden-horizon-sunset-1024x683.jpg 1024w, http://localhost:8888/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/golden-horizon-sunset-1152x768.jpg 1152w"
      sizes="(max-width: 576px) 100vw, 576px" />
  </a>
  <figcaption itemprop="caption description">
    The Golden Horizon </figcaption>
</figure>
```

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

Image src cannot be animated. But you can change small image before animation with big image and then animate size of new one.
But this will open for you new problems: new image will not be loaded immidiatly, so you can:

1) ignore this problem

2) always preload important big images (but this is very bad prcatice)

3) change image on big version only after full loading (more time to code).

All of these not ideal.